# UDP Broadcast blocked over WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a piece of code that send a UDP broadcast to local network (ip "192.168.3.255", port 48620) that work fine when using ethernet connection. However, when using WiFi I do not receive anything back from the scanned devices.

Is it possible that WiFi configuration is blocking the UDP Broadcast ?

If I open the socket when connected to ethernet and start scanning, then unplug ethernet, the scan keeps working using WiFi.

Its following this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004044/reading-from-udp-socket-over-wifi-always-timeout because its not likely linked to the code

```
Carte réseau sans fil Connexion réseau sans fil :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : ltech.local
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::a897:46eb:b97f:de0a%13
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.3.136
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.1

Carte Ethernet Connexion au réseau local :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : ltech.local
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::3823:c78a:c599:dd6b%11
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.3.134
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.1
```

Comment: Have you verified you are connecting the same subnet?  "Is it possible that WiFi configuration is blocking the UDP Broadcast?" - Very unlikely, based on the information you provided, it's not possible determine.

Comment: I've added my ipconfig output for the two adapters. How can I determine what is blocking the UDP broadcast?

Comment: You have tried to assign both the wireless adaptor and the network adaptor the same ip address to confirm, like in a comment in your SO indicate, is not a routing issue?

Comment: I cant change my ip on both adapters. (If i do, i lose access to network and my ip is emptied in the configuration window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, it was a code issue, not a router issue.

More detailled answer available on stackoverflow.